# How can I test existence of a file with permissions 000?

Tags: linux, bash, file-permissions

For some reason I'm not aware of, I've a file with permissions set to '000'.

I'd like to `chmod u+r` it, because I need to zip its entire folder. And with 000, zip warn about a problem reading this file.

I'd like to test existence of this file, because not every time I've it into the folder.

But I verified that using the following results is a boolean false

```
if [ -f $file_path ]; then 
...
```

Also the -e switch return false.

How can I test if file exists from a bash script ?

Comment: Your diagnostics are wrong. The file's permissions only matter when you attempt to open the file. Maybe check the containing directory's permissions, though.

Comment: The lack of quoting could be a problem, though. Try `[ -f "$file_path" ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search a directory for files that have `000` permissions with this statement:

```
find /tmp  -perm 000
```

where `/tmp` would be your directory.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do as you suggest:

```
$> touch none_foo
$> chmod 000 none_foo
$> if [ -f "none_foo" ]; then printf "yes\n"; else printf "no\n"; fi
yes
```

But then if the enclosing folder has 000 you are *doomed* ;-)

Sample (continuing from above state):

```
$> mkdir disclosed
$> mv none_foo disclosed/
# still ok:
$> if [ -f "disclosed/none_foo" ]; then printf "yes\n"; else printf "no\n"; fi
yes
# now a non-disclosure:
$> chmod 000 disclosed
$> if [ -f "disclosed/none_foo" ]; then printf "yes\n"; else printf "no\n"; fi
no
```

So with folders in the file path that forbid "entering" you have to correct that first. 
And in any case (as another commenter alreday suggested): Use quotes around literals and variables in shell ...

As @JeremyJStarcher posted in his answer you can also use:

```
$> find ./ -perm 000
.//disclosed
find: .//disclosed: Permission denied
```

but as you see, the folder trap is to be mitigated by a user with sufficient rights to augment the 000 to something more accessible ...